# getting a custom error error message and redirect url from jqXhR in grails and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, redirect

I'm working on a grails project and can't for the life of me figure out how to accomplish this task.  Basically I have a page that fires an ajax request to a controller.  The controller then checks to see if the resource is valid and sends back a 410 to the client implying that the resource is gone.  The client then opens a jquery dialog and tells the user he's going to get redirected because the resource is invalid. Here's the code I'm using to do that:

```
response.setStatus(410, message)
   def message =message(code:'default.listing.expired.message', args:[email]).toString()
    response.setStatus(410, message)
    forward action:"list"
    return
```

So I'm expecting to see my customer message when I do jqXHR.statusText but I just get the stock HTTP "Gone" message.  Also, how do I access the URL the server is forwarding to (forward action:"list") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should respond with an JSON (or XML, or anything that you can easily read on client side), try:

```
response.setStatus(410) //set response status
def data = [
  message: message(code:'default.listing.expired.message', args:[email]).toString(),
  link: createLinkTo(action: 'list')
]
render(data as JSON) //send response data as JSON
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it was viable solution to the problem.  Thanks for the suggestion!